# oracle sql query to format number by comma

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys i want to print the following data with comma separated values using oracle sql

```
696585242087


to 

69,658,524,2087
```

and same for the decimal.

Comment: Why would you want a comma before the right most 4 digits?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(696585242087, '99G999G999G9999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=",."')
FROM    dual
```

Comment: +1 Allows for [countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma) that use a decimal comma

Comment: What if I don't know how many digits the source number have, I mean is there any pattern to group every 3 digits regardless of number's length?

Answer (score 29):

See [the Oracle docs](http://www.oradev.com/oracle_number_format.jsp) for all the insanity that can be done for number formatting. The short version is you need the "TO_CHAR" function, and provide a formatting string for the output:

```
TO_CHAR( col_name, '999,999,999,999')
```

Should do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

take a look to to_char: http://www.oradev.com/oracle_number_format.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Taking the [Dead programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378968/dead-programmer)'s update (24/Jan/2011) (*original author of the question*) and the comment of [Amir Pashazadeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690553/amir-pashazadeh) (5/Mar/2016), we can get the desired comma separated format with the following example.

> *This code applies for numbers with equal or less than 15 digits, if
> you will need for bigger length, you should add more 999,999 according
> with the max of length you will manage.*

```
SELECT TRIM(TO_CHAR(12345678, '999,999,999,999,999')) ttry FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT TRIM(TO_CHAR(    1234, '999,999,999,999,999')) ttry FROM DUAL
;
```

### Result:

[image]