# how to convert the numeric into indian currency format in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

suppose i have column money say its value is eg:880856.00 i need a query to format this money column like this 8,80,856.00

Comment: [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783760/oracle-sql-query-to-format-number-by-comma)

Answer (score 1):

You can use to_char to format characters.

So, for the format you have specified

```
to_char(money, '9,99,999.99' );
```

Would return 8,80,856.00

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v4c9.png)

It should be noted that this is simply the length of the string provided in the first answer, and a longer second argument can be provided to properly format the number as desired.

So:

```
to_char(11111111111111.11, '9,99,999,99,9,99,999.99')
```

Would return 1,11,111,11,1,11,111.11

[extra length example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt9LD.png)

This will also automatically adjust for the number of digits provided in the first argument, for instance:

```
to_char(5856.00, '9,99,999.99');
```

Would return 5,856.00

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDxTU.png)

From the Oracle docs:
https://www.oradev.com/oracle_number_format.jsp

Here's an old stackoverflow post on the topic: [oracle sql query to format number by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783760/oracle-sql-query-to-format-number-by-comma)

Comment: what if i dont know the length of my column

Comment: @Shah the answer is now updated

Comment: Whilst this will eventually give the correct answer, it will only do it for numbers up to 999999.99. Seeing that we're talking about indian currency (rupees), that is 13.423,27 USD. It's easy to run out of numbers. I'd suggest @Shah to handle this within the displayed application, since another issue can arise and that is that you will not be able to use any analytical functions, without creating another column to get numbers, but you'll have to convert them in the end either way.

Comment: @Tilin You can add as many commas/places as needed by simply increasing the length of the second argument and formatting as desired. Although it is a fair point that analytics can't be run with these numbers as it is more just for visualization; I'm unsure of how one might store that data in the database in such a format and then also perform analytics in that same format.

Comment: That is why you shouldn't output, nor store the numbers in such format. They should be returned in as a number type and then formatted within said application.

Comment: I didn't expect Oracle's thousand separator to be so flexible. I thought it would always make three-digit blocks, as we know from the international numbering system. It is good to see that Oracle is able to format to the Indian system, too. With a long enough format like `'99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,990.99'` this should cover the case. I don't see why analytic functions are an argumant here, because the number is stored in a numeric format and only converted to a string. But yes, it is way better to have the app or Website do the formatting instead of the DBMS anyway.